# Return to Visualforce/ Apex after popping a second Visualforce/Apex page

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I want to be able to return to a specific visualforce page after I navigate away from it.

Here's the procedure:
1)The rep will be on the visualforce page and click on a button that will present them a case.
2)The user decides they can't work it, so they click the javascript button I've created called return to queue. This is just another visualforce page that pops up.
3)This pops a visualforce page that let's them type the reason and click save.
4) I want the original visualforce page to load here.

How do you kick that off from the visualforce page that is popped up?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this have to be visualforce/Apex only?  or can it be @RemoteAction and javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this to relocate the parent window from the popup:

For the custom Visualforce pages:

```
window.opener.location = '/apex/yourCustomPageName';
```

For the standard Salesforce page layouts:

```js
window.opener.location = '/' + standardPageId;
```